# jQuery drop-down menu would not position horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a drop-down menu that has an `on-click` drop-down (rather than `hover`). I found this great script, but I can't seem to get the links to line up horizontally. I can't figure out if it's the positioning or something else. I tried adding floats and inline styles, but neither worked.

**CSS**

```
.click-nav 
{
width:150px;
border-top: 5px solid #333;
border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
}

.click-nav ul 
{
position:relative;
font-weight:900; 
}

.click-nav ul li 
{
position:relative;
list-style:none;
cursor:pointer;
}

.click-nav ul li ul 
{
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
}

.click-nav ul .clicker 
{
position:relative;
background:#FFF;
color:#333;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.click-nav ul .clicker:hover,.click-nav ul .active 
{
background:#333;
color: #FFF;
}

 .click-nav img 
{
position:absolute;top:9px;left:12px;
}

.click-nav ul li a 
{
transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:background-color      0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;      
display:block;
padding:8px 10px 8px 40px;
background:#333;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
}

.click-nav ul li a:hover 
{
background:#333;
color: #d48f3a;
}

/* Fallbacks */
.click-nav .no-js ul {display:none;}
.click-nav .no-js:hover ul {display:block;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="click-nav">
<ul class="no-js">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="clicker">music</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Featured Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CDs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vinyl</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#" class="clicker">movies</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Featured Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DVDs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blu-Ray</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3D Blu-Ray</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
```

**jQuery Script**

```
$(function () {
    // Clickable Dropdown
    $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
    $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
    $('.click-nav .js').click(function (e) {
        $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
        $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function () {
        if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
            $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
            $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What kind of script are you using? Is it a superfish plugin by any chance?

Comment: I'm using this one: http://toddmotto.com/flawless-clickable-drop-down-navigation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the 1st level nav items, the reason is because you have `A` tag within the `LI` with `display:block` style.

```
.click-nav ul li a 
{
transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:background-color      0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;      
display:block;
padding:8px 10px 8px 40px;
background:#333;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

### Update

http://jsfiddle.net/nsjtB/1/

Get rid of `display:block` as it spans the full width and restricts the `LI` to display inline.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have messed it up a little though. I set it up here without the display: block 

http://jsfiddle.net/XHbJx/

Comment: It seems to be working with 1 ul item http://jsfiddle.net/nsjtB/. Is your problem with 2 ULs?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have about 7 ULs each with their own drop downs lined up horizontally.

Comment: Ok, it's not a big problem to align all items horizontally http://jsfiddle.net/nsjtB/1/ . But you realize that the plugin you are using is designed for single item. You need to tweak and modify the script in order to accommodate multiple items and respond to subsequent item click. If so, that's a different question overall.

Comment: Yeah, that was my fear actually. Thanks though, this was very helpful.

Comment: Also, if your list is not dynamic (database driven) and you have fixed number of items. I would suggest you to write your own simplified code using jQuery toggle/toggleClass method. Pretty simple actually.

Answer (score 0):

No need for inline styles. Looks like you are missing a closing  tag. If you float the LIs left you can get them to line up horizontally. I assume you have javascript for the rest of the functionality but you would get the 2 LIs to line up horizontally like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/74x6N/8/

```
.click-nav ul > li 
{
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: This lines them up as I'd like, but now the drop-downs aren't working, I've added the script: http://jsfiddle.net/74x6N/2/

Comment: Hey sorry to get back to you so late but I have modified the script. You need to include jQuery in jsfiddle for your code to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/74x6N/8/

Try this out and let me know if you have questions on how it works.